# need some advice regarding the efficiency of running linear model for the analysis

Tags: regression

I have a continuous dependent, a categorical variable and a continuous covariate (Age). I apply linear regression and here are the results. Do you think applying the linear model is appropriate? The first plot is residuals vs Age and the second plot is dependent variable vs categorical variable and the third one is residuals vs fitted value.

[image: <code>[![enter image description here][1]][1]</code>]
[image]

After taking the log of the dependent variable the plot of residuals vs fitted values would be something like 
[image]

Do you recommend me applying the linear regression for this analysis? I mean, is there any linear relationship between age and dependent variable? Should I remove the outliers?

Comment: It looks alright but you might want to transform the dependent variable so that the residuals will be closer to normally distributed.

Comment: @ Great38, Hi, thanks for the comment. I got log of the dependent variable and I added a new plot. Do you still recommend me applying the linear regression? Especially do you think the relationship between dependent variable and age is linear?

Comment: the relationship between the raw dependent variable and age looks linear enough. It would be useful to look at a plot of residuals vs fitted values for your model with the logged dependent variable and both covariates- use that to assess linearity and normality.

Comment: @ Great38, Thanks for the comment. I added the plot of residuals vs fitted values. Do you recommend me to remove the outliers?

Comment: that looks pretty good. It is still a little skewed but I don't recommend removing outliers unless you know those data points are wrong.